# Dependency Injection with Azure Isolated Function

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a isolated function app rnning .net 7.
I also have 4 other projects in the solution. And I need to use services from those other projects. I am using dependency injection. But when I try to reference those services for use, it is giving me errors:
Unable to resolve service for type "Microsoft.Extension.caching.distrubted, Idistributeccache", while attempting to activate PROJ.Infrastructure.Persistence.Cache.CacheUtility' at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites.....
Has anyone run into this situation before?

I tried to make it an non-isolated function app, but the way my solution is set up, I currently need the function app to be isolated.

Comment: did you ever solve this? im running into a similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK,  In .NET Core, the default [session provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0) provides the [IDistributedCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0) property record that is used to store the cache of external services using.

To resolve the error, either you remove the Session related methods like **`UseSession`** that uses the **`IDistributedCache`** property or add the properties to the services class such as `services.AddMemoryCache()` and then `services.AddControllers`